# click event not firing in firefox - backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following view:

```
App.HouseListElemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    events: {
        'click': function() {
            App.detailsRouter.navigate('details/' + this.model.id, true);     
        },
        'click .btn-compare': 'compare',
        'click .btn-compare > input': 'toggleCompare',
    },
   // more stuff here...
 });
```

The first click event in the list is triggered in both safari and chrome, but not in firefox. I am using firefox 11.0.

Am I declaring my events incorrectly?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Those events are fine in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vKHdc/

Comment: That's interesting.. It does work in firefox like that. I don't know what could be wrong then. My html is a `ul` with various list items inside..

Comment: Adjust the fiddle to match the HTML you're using or include your template and `render` in the question. My first guess is that you're generating invalid HTML and Firefox is correcting it in ways that screw up your event delegation.

Comment: updated your jsfiddle with template: http://jsfiddle.net/vKHdc/1/ oddly it works in firefox with the template.

Comment: After looking into this further, I realized that the events for `click .btn-compare` are being fired even though I am not clicking on them, but on the li that contains them. Why is this happening?

Comment: `click .btn-compare` will be hit due to bubbling, `return false` or `ev.stopPropagation()` in the handlers will stop the bubbling.

Comment: added e.stopPropagation() and they are still being hit. Not in the jsfiddle though :S

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vKHdc/3/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are doing it incorrectly. Do the below and it should work

```
App.HouseListElemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    events: {
        'click': 'navigateTo',
        'click .btn-compare': 'compare',
        'click .btn-compare > input': 'toggleCompare',
    },
    navigateTo:function() {
            App.detailsRouter.navigate('details/' + this.model.id, true);
        },
   // more stuff here...
 });
```

and by the way the click event will be bound to root of view which is `el`. So do specify the target of click using a selected like `'click #navigator':'navigateTo'`

Comment: According to the docs: "Events are written in the format {"event selector": "callback"}. The callback may be either the name of a method on the view, or a direct function body."

Comment: I do want the event to be bound to the el. However, I changed `click` to `click li` and it started working.

Comment: Using anonymous functions in `events` is fine with newer Backbones.

Comment: @muistooshort just a doubt. I have a model that has collection associated with it. As per the docs the default implementation of `url` it should do post,get to `collection_url/model_id` but it always does it to `collection_url` **only**. What should i do to make it work as per the docs

Comment: Do you have `url` or `urlRoot` set anywhere?

Comment: @muistooshort no. does it make a difference? I did try but that way too but the requests are now mapped to the url root. The model has a collection mapped to it, but seems the request is not mapped. May be you could try it with a fiddle

Comment: Do you model instances have `collection` properties? Maybe you should ask a question so that we cane see more details.

Comment: @muistooshort by `The model has a collection mapped to it` i meant this `new collection({model:myModel});`. the model belongs to a collection. But then as per docs the url are not built

Comment: Collection constructors (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-constructor) don't work like that, you set the `model` when creating the collection "class" through `Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: ...})`.